# Which of the following are subspaces of $F[-1,1]=\{f \mid f: [-1,1] \to\mathbb{R}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following are subspaces of $F[-1,1]=\{f \mid f: [-1,1] \to\mathbb{R}\}$?
$$\begin{align}
X&= \{f \in F[-1,1] \mid f(-1)= f(1)\}  \\\\
Y&= \{f \in F[-1,1] \mid f(0)= -1\}  \\\\
Z&= \{f \in F[-1,1] \mid f(x)=f(y), \text{ for every }x,y \in[-1,1]\}  \\\\
W&= \{f \in F[-1,1] \mid f(-1) \leq 0\}
\end{align}$$

My answer:

$X$ is a subspace because it passes the subspace test.

$Y$ isn't because it doesn't pass the first test, the zero test.

$Z$ also isn't because it's asking for every $x$, which means $x$ will not equal zero

$W$ I'm not sure...

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/08fd3a21-27da-446f-a409-b35ecebaca13/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ *is* a subspace; it consists of all the constant functions. The zero function is constant, so it's in $Z$.

$W$ is not a subspace since, for instance, if $f(x) = -1$ is the constant $-1$ function, then $-f \notin W$ since $-f(-1) = 1 > 0$.